# Why can the state $\sum_x|x, f(x)\rangle$ be written without normalization factor?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

It is stated on page 32 of Nielsen and Chuang that:

> In our single qubit example: [image],
> measurement of the state gives only either |0, f(0)> or |1, f(1)>!
> Similarly, in the general case, measurement of the state $\sum_x|x, f(x)\rangle$ would give only f(x) for a single value of x.

Why is it that the state $\sum_x|x, f(x)\rangle$ doesn't contain normalization?

Comment: While the answers below are correct, I think Nielsen and Chuang usually write the normalization factor, so this might be an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

When we consider an uniform (or equal, as stated in Nielsen and Chuang) superposition, that is, a state that can be written as:
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_x|x\rangle,$$
it is quite common not to write the normalisation constant $\frac{1}{2^n}$. Similarly, when the amplitutes of all vectors on the superposition are equal, we omit the normalisation constant. So for instance, even though the following state is not an uniform superposition (the first register *is* in an uniform superposition, not the whole state), we omit the normalisation constant $\frac{1}{2^n}$:
$$|\varphi\rangle=\sum_x|x\rangle|0\rangle.$$
Now, if you were to apply $f$ on this state, there would still be no need to write explicitely the normalisation constant, hence the notation:
$$\sum_x|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle.$$

Putting things differently, this state *is* normalized, but we don't explicitely write the normalisation constant for conciseness' sake.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum (pure) states are, by definition, defined up to a scalar complex factors. That means that a state that we write as $|\psi\rangle$, should really be understood as the full set of vectors (an *equivalence class* if you will) $\{\lambda|\psi\rangle : \lambda\in\mathbb C\}$.

The more formal way to put this is to say that quantum states are elements in the *[complex projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space)*. For example, single qubits are elements of the complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

In other words, $|\psi\rangle$, $2|\psi\rangle$, $\lambda|\psi\rangle$, etc, for any $|\psi\rangle$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, all represent the same identical physical state.
Of course, if you work with unnormalised vectors, you will have to make sure all formulas you use are changed accordingly. For example, given an unnormalised state $|\psi\rangle=|0\rangle+|1\rangle$, the probability of finding $|0\rangle$ will read
$$p = \frac{|\langle0|\psi\rangle|^2}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}=\frac12.$$